MS Surface power supply connector
This is an update to the first question about this connector.
I had 3 faulty Microsoft Surface power supplies and I draw a topological circuit diagram for it, to better compare it with the hardware.

The main difference from the diagram in the first question is, that the cathode of the LEDs is connected to the (blue) control line.
Here the connector:

It ends up, that 3 volt supplied by the Microsoft Surface device (at the pin where D5 and R6 are attached) will turn on the MOSFET.
This MOSFET then connects the control line to ground.
This signals the power supply to supply power.
Since the anode of the LED2 is connected to power and the cathode of the LEDs is connected to the control line, they begin to light up, if power is supplied and MOSFET is turned on.
Here the signal of the unconnected control line:

Especially if the control line is accidentally connected to the power line, the MOSFET will break.
Here a picture with the replaced MOSFET, which was broken on all my connectors:

And here a picture of an alternate connector using the same circuit:

What is unclear to me, is the fact that there are resistors R2 and R4 and 3 pins of Q1 which seems not used. But this TSOP 6 package prevents this connector from being easily repaired :-(.
Does anyone know what the reason for these extra parts is and why the MOSFETs fail so often, even if no short circuit can be detected between the power and control lines?

You can get MOSFETs in 6 pin packages for better heatsinking Are you replacing like with like?

@Finbarr But you are aware, that the source is at pin 4, gate is at pin 5 and drain at pin 6?
I could not find any replacement for this layout :-(
